# That comes from the sensor

Tags: ios, xcode, camera, sensors

I need access in console to sensor information when the camera is running for example:

```
  NSLog(@"value senson camera");
```

Comment: Please read the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) and edit the question

Comment: [Check this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

This question has already been answered 
Invoke method  AVCaptureSession To access the camera Then use this method to access the sensor

Create NSSrting Sensor

```
@property (strong,nonatomic) NSString *Sensor;



#pragma mark - Styling methods

- (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput  didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer fromConnection: (AVCaptureConnection *)connection
{
CFDictionaryRef metadataDict = CMCopyDictionaryOfAttachments(NULL,
                                                              sampleBuffer, kCMAttachmentMode_ShouldPropagate);
NSDictionary *metadata = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]
                          initWithDictionary:(__bridge  NSDictionary*)metadataDict];
CFRelease(metadataDict);
NSDictionary *exifMetadata = [[metadata objectForKey:(NSString  *)kCGImagePropertyExifDictionary] mutableCopy];
float brightnessValue = [[exifMetadata objectForKey:(NSString  *)kCGImagePropertyExifBrightnessValue] floatValue];

//HERE IS YOU SENSOR INFO
_Sensor = [[NSNumber numberWithFloat:brightnessValue] stringValue];
 NSLog(@"VALUE SENSOR %@",_Sensor);

dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 0.5 * NSEC_PER_SEC);
dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){


        if ([_Sensor isEqualToString:@"YOU VALUE"]) {

           //YOU CODE HERE 

        }   

});


}
```

Enjoy

Comment: If this question has already been answered, you should flag the question as a duplicate and link to the duplicate question in the future.